# Pandas finding identifiers with a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataset:

| ID | Purchased |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 0 |
| 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 1 |
| 102 | 0 |
| 102 | 0 |
| 102 | 0 |
| 102 | 0 |
| 103 | 1 |
| 103 | 1 |
| 103 | 1 |
| 103 | 1 |
| 104 | 0 |
| 104 | 1 |
| 104 | 0 |
| 104 | 1 |

In a pandas dataframe how could I locate and count the following the ID that have only the Purchased value of ‘1’ reoccurring (like ID: 101 and 103). And also how can I locate and count the identifiers that have changing binary values (Like ID: 100 and 104).

I have tried to use the .diff along with groupby ID but it didn’t work.
`df[‘diffPurchased’]= df.groupby(‘ID’)[‘Purchased’].diff()`

Then I took the new feature diffPurchased to return the rows that have a changing ‘Purchased’ variable but it still didn’t accurately return all changing identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest if you want visual inspection might be to use an aggregation as set:

```
out = df.groupby('ID')['Purchased'].agg(set)
```

Output:

```
ID
100    {0, 1}
101       {1}
102       {0}
103       {1}
104    {0, 1}
Name: Purchased, dtype: object
```

Then you can do:

```
out[out == {1}].index.tolist()
# [101, 103]

out[out == {0, 1}].index.tolist()
# [100, 104]
```

Or even:

```
out = df.groupby('ID')['Purchased'].agg(frozenset)
dic = out.index.groupby(out)
print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{(1): [101, 103], (0): [102], (0, 1): [100, 104]}
```

Comment: I wanted to return a count value and a list of identifies that meet two conditions (IDs have only purchased value 1 or ID has a changing sequence of purchased) as my dataset is huge and using agg would be impossible to view all the identifiers